# Postdoc joining Appointment delay for few weeks

Tags: postdocs, joint-appointment

I got a particular postdoc position in the USA that has a start date of 1st DEC 2021. However, I would need to delay the start date for at least two weeks, it would not be possible for me join at Dec 1st. I want to join around 15-20 dec. Because i have very urgent priority work at the beginning of december (I was not aware of that before).

How common is it to delay the start of a postdoc position for a few weeks? Who is the right person to contact? And how can I convince them?

Answer (score 1):

Deferral of postdoctoral position is very common. Two weeks in December is most probably harmless for the department because you most probably are not going to be assigned any teaching for that time. But you need to contact the Chair as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you. Can I contact with them after getting Visa??? Because Untill now i got only Offer letter.

Comment: I think that you need to contact the Chair as soon as possible. A visa can take several months. But I do not know for sure, it depends on the department.

Comment: I am asking because My HR said , start date is December 1, 2021.  This does not have to be the actual arrival date, they can adjust it depends on my visa.